# Redirection based on user role upon login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, roles

I am trying to redirect user to page based on their role.  Below is the login code in a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(User model)
    {
        // Lets first check if the Model is valid or not
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (AuthenticationAppEntities1 entities = new AuthenticationAppEntities1())
            {
                string username = model.Username;
                string password = model.Password;

                // Now if our password was enctypted or hashed we would have done the
                // same operation on the user entered password here, But for now
                // since the password is in plain text lets just authenticate directly

                bool userValid = entities.Users.Any(user => user.Username == username && user.Password == password);
                // User found in the databases
                if (userValid)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
                    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.Roles, "admin"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Home", "Authentication");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("HomeAdmin", "Authentication");
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

As you can see in the code, I redirect users based on their roles, using a if.  However, model.Roles contain a null value as the controller is getting only the username and password from the login page.  Any simple idea how I get the role of the authenticated user?  I thought of searching it through the username, but am not sure if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the User's roles and then compare it with 'admin' and then redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm not even sure how you're getting that to run in the first place. The method signature for `Roles.IsUserInRole` is:

```
Roles.IsUserInRole(string username, string role);
```

Passing `model.Roles` is neither a string, nor a username, if it was a string.